# Vue, how can I render different navbar due to route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new at Vue.js. I am working on demo project. In my project, I have three different navbar. First one for HomePage, second one for Login/Register page and third one is for Dashboard. In frameworks like React and Vue  we set one global navbar for all pages. How can I render this three navbar components conditionally ? What is the best practice for that ? I want to set vuex for solve that, is that a right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you can do is make a navbar component and use v-if to check on which route you are currently on. You can use the $route object to verify the current URL and use computed to check if the route name or params/queries are the same as you want.

```
computed: {
  dashboard() {
     return this.$route.name === 'Dashboard'
  }
}
```

And then in your navbar component use v-if="dashboard" to check your conditions

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using named routes. In your component you set multiple named router views:

```
  <router-view name="navbar"></router-view>
  <router-view ></router-view>
```

And in routes you set which component to render and where:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: HomeContent,
        navbar: HomeNavbar,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      components: {
        default: DashboardContent,
        navbar: DashboardNavbar,
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Otherwise you can set a conditional in the component and render navbar based on route:

```
  if ($route.path === home) {
   <NavbarHome />
  }
```

If navbars have much in common you can just use a conditional for elements that are in one but not in another.